# How to submit a form using jest when useRef react hook is used?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I'm trying to submit a form using jest, but not sure how to pass the field values. I get the form errors with the message saying the fields are required.  Below is my component.

```
export const LimitUpdate: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
   const [formKey, setFormKey] = React.useState(0);
   const [description, setDescription] = React.useState("");
   React.useEffect(() => {
    if (props.submitSR) {
      const thisForm = serlimitIncFormRef.current;
      const formErrors = thisForm.triggerValidation();
      if (!formErrors || Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0) {
        onSubmit();
      } else {
        props.onSubmitComplete();
      }
    }
  }, [props.submitSR]);

  const serlimitIncFormRef = React.useRef<FormRef>();
  const incrementFormKey = (): void => {
    setFormKey(formKey + 1);
  };
 const validate = (values: FormValues): FormErrors => {
 //Form Validation
 };
 const setLimitIncFormRef = (form: FormRef): FormRef => {
    serlimitIncFormRef.current = form;
    return form;
  };
  const internalRender = (): JSX.Element => {
    <Form
          testId="legacyForm"
          key={formKey}
          formRef={setLimitIncFormRef}
          onSubmit={onSubmit}
          validator={validate}
        >
        <ContactDetails/>
        <ProblemSummary
            maxLength={MAX_DESCRIPTION_LEN}
            text={description}
            setText={setDescription}
          />
    </Form>

  };
};
```

The onSubmit() doesn't get invoked because the field values are empty and the `thisForm.triggerValidation()` returns formErrors with the fields. I believe I need to mock the useRef for Form, but not sure. Below is the test, and I able to click the form but as I said I'm not able to invoke the onSubmit() method through the test

```
const props = {
  onSubmitComplete: () => {},
  setSev1Confirmed: () => {},
  setSeverity: () => {} ,
  submitSR: false,
  severity: "MEDIUM" as TicketSeverityEnum,
  sev1Confirmed: false,
  srType: "limit" as SupportType
};
describe("create limit update support request", () => {
     it("test form submission", async() => {
    props.submitSR = true;
    const  { getByOuiTestId,debug }   = render(<LimitUpdateSRCreate {...props}/>);
    const form = getByOuiTestId("legacyLimitsForm");
    const name = getByOuiTestId("name-id");
    expect(name).toBeDefined();
    fireEvent.change(name, { target: { value: "test" } });
    const email = getByOuiTestId("email-id");
    expect(email).toBeDefined();
    fireEvent.submit(form);
  });

});
```

Comment: You don't need to mock it, just simulate entering data into the from.

Comment: Thanks that worked. When I debug I could see the values. But  I enter the 3 textfields like below ```fireEvent.change(email, { target: { value: "test@test.com" } }); fireEvent.change(problemSummary, { target: { value: "test" } });fireEvent.change(name, { target: { value: "test" } });``` only the first field gets the value, the other fields still says invalid.

Comment: I get an error ```Unable to find an element by: [data-test-id="email-id"]```. But I do see the id with email-id in the debug() statement
```<input data-test-id="email-id" name="Email" tabindex="0" type="text" value="" />```

Comment: I'd suggest giving a [mre] of the problem filling the form, then.

Comment: @jonrsharpe,
Updated the test, I'm able to enter the name fields but email field the change event is not working and hence the form throws error saying email is a required field.

Comment: So, I debugged and noticed that when I the fireEvent.change for nameInput triggers the useEffect method gets invoked and validation fails. Perfect, But when the second input fields fireEvent triggers (i.e email) the useEffect doesn't trigger. Do I need to trigger anything from the test so that useEffect triggers again?

Comment: I wasn't passing the right way the reactHooks. That worked. Thanks @jonrsharpe